# Char buffer with multiple null char

Tags: c, cassandra, datastax

I am working on a socket program(using `recvfrom`) which returns me a buffer of char. However the received data contains multiple `null` chars and it does not let me post process it easily.

I would like to request if there is any way to escape the null chars if they are found in the middle of the buffer ?

Goal is to store the binary data into cassandra DB. I tried to ignore the null chars and store it directly into the DB. However it will only store the partial string. On research I learnt that I could use `TextAsBlob()` function to convert the received data into blob. Although this did not changed anything , only partial data is stored in the DB.(till the first null is seen).

So,  I need to know is there a way to escape them? I have the length of the received data available.

For printing the data I am  printing the data using `%c` byte by byte.

Structure of table:

```
cqlsh:network> desc packet;

CREATE TABLE network.packet (
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    value blob
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

cqlsh:network>



cqlsh:network> SELECT * from packet;

 key                                            | value
------------------------------------------------+--------------------
 1234                                           |     0x70e54c5bfd7f
 1235
```

Error:

```
cqlsh:network> SELECT blobAsText(value) FROM network.packet WHERE key = '1234' ;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="In call to function system.blobastext, value 0x70e54c5bfd7f is not a valid binary representation for type text"
```

Insert command:

```
 char key[5] = 1234;
// value is received from socket. 

INSERT INTO network.packet (key, value) VALUES (key, value);
```

Comment: By definition a C string ends with a NUL character. If you need "strings" that contain NUL characters, you need to handle this yourself by storing the length of the string somehow.

Comment: In general, keeping the big binary data in Cassandra isn't very good idea...

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that this data shouldn't be referred to as text, and then you're using `TextToBlob()` to store it. `TextToBlob()` would refer to your data as **text** (and would try to store it as binary data) but that's exactly what you wouldn't want. Because if it would have been referred to as text every 0 would mean string-termination.

You'd want to store this data received by `recvfrom` in some pointer to some data structure or maybe just a `void *`. Because otherwise, every byte which is `null` (0) will be referred to as end-of-string.

So, you should allocate some memory in the size you say you know, and then read all this data to this address not using any strings (char arrays) functions.

Comment: is there any way in Cassandra to ignore null and store directly by the length(start and end position) ? like , do not think and store the data

Comment: @monk Well that's another question, and I'm not a Cassandra expert, but from a quick search you can probably use [blob data type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html)

Comment: from that post only I reached to use `TestAsBlob` function, which will stop at first null char.

Comment: @monk `TestAsBlob()` is a conversion function. Why are you trying to convert it? Just define the table column as `blob` type and then insert this data. No conversion is needed.

Comment: but , If I do not then `select` will not work, it will give error `0x234123  is not a valid binary representation for type text`

Comment: Is the column for this data in your table defined as `blob`? It's a bit impossible to help without seeing how your table is defined and how your `SELECT` command looks like, but one thing is sure - if you don't store this data as blob you wouldn't be able to read it.

Comment: I have updated the question with `desc` of table and a `select *` for clarity.

Comment: You should also add how you store the data in the table

Comment: updated in the question. blob/binary data is received through socket and key is something I hardcode.

Comment: Where's `value` defined?

Comment: value is received through the socket into buffer

Comment: Where is it **defined**? Its C definition

Comment: `const char * value`